# Assigning interface instance to a class that implements that interface

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0

I have various classes that implements IActiveRecord.

I want to have a method where I pass in a newly created class and assign ActiveRecord to the type of the class passed in.

I have tried the below but it does not compile for some reason.

Any ideas?

```
private void AddRecord<T>() where T : class, new()
        {

            IActiveRecord ActiveRecord = (IActiveRecord)T;
        }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you just need to add the constraint `where T : IActiveRecord`. Then you can say

```
void AddRecord<T>() where T : IActiveRecord, new() { 
    IActiveRecord activeRecord = new T();
    // more stuff
}
```

Regarding your line

> `IActiveRecord ActiveRecord = (IActiveRecord)T;`

this is not legal. `T` is a type parameter, not an expression that you can cast.

Comment: Even though new is passed in as new()

Answer (score 2):

In the method you're displaying, you do not pass in an instance of a certain type ?
I do not really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Do you want to do this:

```
private void AddRecord<T>() where T : IActiveRecord, new()
{
    IActiveRecord a = new T();
}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to constrain the generic type to be of type `IActiveRecord`, then you don't need the cast:

```
private void AddRecord<T>() where T : IActiveRecord, new()
{
    IActiveRecord a = new T();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to restrict your method by using the following:

```
private void AddRecord<T>() where T : IActiveRecord, new()
```

Otherwise, your question might not be clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for whoever downvoted me, but can you explain why my answer is bad?